# How to avoid that scrollTop function on accordion works for children?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap 4 accordion on my website and inside the accordion a second accordion to show hide additional content:

- MainAccordionHeader 1
- MainAccordionBody 1

  - SubAccordionHeader a
  - SubAccordionHeader b
  - SubAccordionBody a
  - SubAccordionBody b
- MainAccordionHeader 2
- MainAccordionBody 2

...and so on

Here an example:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>


    <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div id="accordionRecommendation">
          <div class="card-header border" id="headingRecommendation">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne1">
                Collapsible Group Item #1
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo1">
                Collapsible Group Item #2
              </button>
              <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree1">
                Collapsible Group Item #3
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div class="karte">
            <div id="collapseOne1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingRecommendation" data-parent="#accordionRecommendation">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="karte">
            <div id="collapseTwo1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingRecommendation" data-parent="#accordionRecommendation">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="karte">
            <div id="collapseThree1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingRecommendation" data-parent="#accordionRecommendation">
              <div class="card-body">
                Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="headingThree">
      <h5 class="mb-0">
        <button class="btn btn-link collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </button>
      </h5>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingThree" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With this function I achieve that the MainAccordionHeader X automatically scroll to the top when opened:

```
$('.card').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top -167
  }, 500);
});
```

Problem is, that the function also applies when the user clicks on a SubAccordionHeader to show content inside of it.

I tried to use a unique identifier instead of card and also tried to add a separate class to the main accordion. But without success.

May somebody explain me how I need to adapt the code to make sure that it only works for the main accordion ant not for the sub inside of it?

Here's a [link](http://schlaganfallrehabilitation.de/repositories/remosapp/test/index.php) and a fiddle with an example code: https://jsfiddle.net/bwuzctj8/.

Comment: I'm not sure hot it possible. if the `SubAccordionHeader` has no `.card` class so it will not listen to the function and will not call the `scrollTop`.

Comment: This is what I've also thought and tried. However, when I change the `card` class in SubAccordionHeader to something else the function will be called... I don't know why...

Comment: Post some sample HTML too.

Comment: here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bwuzctj8/

Answer (score 0):

You can add some class in your sub Accordion button. like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-link collapsed subAccordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
      Collapsible Group Item #2
    </button>
```

And try use this script:

```
$('.card').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('.subAccordion')){
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
  } else {
    var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $card.offset().top -167
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi bagongpct, I updated the script but unfortunately it does not work. Here the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cm8doegt/

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution by my self:

```
$('.card').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e) {
  var $card = $(this).closest('.card');
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $card.offset().top
  }, 500);
});

$('.karte').on('shown.bs.collapse', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Updated fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/bp6oe07k/

Anyway, thanks for helping